# What is the difference between GPON ONU and ONT?

Tags: networking, redistribution

The Optical Network Unit (ONU) and the Optical Network Terminal (ONT) GEEPONs can both connect with an Optical Network Terminal (OLT) via fiber cables in order to achieve an Optical Distributed Network. I've read on different forums that both the ONU and ONT are able to achieve this requirement equally, but since they are both manufactured by the same provider, what really differentiates them?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

ONU is the IEEE term while ONT is the ITU-T term. Both mean the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

ONT: a single-subscriber ONU.

G.987 Clause 5.7 Use of the terms ONU and ONT

> "an ONU that is used for fibre to the home (FTTH) and includes the user port function" (see [b-ITU-T G.983.1]), or "a single-subscriber ONU" (see [b-ITU-T G.984.1] and other documents of the ITU-T G.984 series).

https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-G.987-201206-I/en